# How to use polymorphic datatypes with fclabels?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, lenses

**TL;DR:** I want to use `fclabels` with my polymorphic datatype, but obtaining wired errors with it.

```
data R a = A { cb :: a }
         | B { cb :: a, cd :: a}
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

So, my type is a sum off multiple variants with different number of fields. Some of the fields have the same names and it is important for me.
When I am converting it to underscored version and run `mkLabel` template:

```
data R a = A { _cb :: a }
         | B { _cb :: a, _cd :: a }
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

mkLabel ''R
```

I have some errors that I do not understand:

```
λ :load AminoAcidLens.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling AminoAcidLens    ( AminoAcidLens.hs, interpreted )

AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘cb’
    Declared at: AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1
                 AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1

AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1: error:
    Duplicate type signatures for ‘cb’
    at AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1-11
       AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1-11

AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1: error:
    Duplicate INLINE pragmas for ‘cb’
    at AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1-11
       AminoAcidLens.hs:13:1-11
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

If I change `_cd`s type to any other, the errors disappear:

```
data R a = A { _cb :: a }
         | B { _cb :: a, _cd :: Int }
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

mkLabel ''R
```

So, why do I have these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: In general, you can't have two functions with the same name. You need to enable one of the GHC extensions for record overloading, or roll your own.

Comment: Looks like `fclabels` is not up for the task. [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) has no problem with your code, and is generally better-suited for polymorphic updates. (Also, its Van Laarhoven style is increasingly becoming the standard, so if only for compatibility it might make sense to go that route.) — However, I wonder whether your ADT structure is really optimal... why not `data R a = R { _cb :: a, _cd :: Maybe a }`?

Comment: Thanks, I moved to `lens` and it works. Really I have 20 constructors with different fields and I really need the names of these constructors.